# Uncaught promise with babel-polyfill

Tags: javascript, babeljs

There is the following simple code:

```
  function getPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject();
    })
  }

  getPromise().then(() => {});
```

As you can see I just return promise which are always reject, but I don't want to catch it. So, I see in console error:

```
Uncaught (in promise)
```

I don't want to catch it, but I don't want to see this error. What should I do? I use babel-polyfill.

Comment: "*but I don't want to catch it.*" - why not? Either you have to live with the console error, or catch the error and explicitly ignore it (do nothing). Or just don't reject your promise.

Answer (score 0):

You are rejecting a promise and not catching it. Simply catch the error and do nothing with it. That is the only way to handle rejected promises in vanilla JS <s>until the `finally` method makes it into the spec, [probably for ES2018](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally).</s>

```
getPromise().then(() => {}).catch(() => {});
```